# To get no. of buttons on Google homepage using Static descriptive programming in QTP

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I wanted to count no. of objects on Google homepage using static programming, i mean without creating object first(the way we do in dynamic one).

Pls tell me what is wrong in below statement

```
Set P = Browser("creationtime:=0").page("title:=Google").WebButton("type:=submit","html tag:=INPUT")

MsgBox P.Count()
```

Pls help, screenshot of error is attached here.

Thanks

Comment: For starters, you're missing a quote in your `WebButton()` call.

Comment: Thanks for correction, yes just forgot it here, however above corrected code still doesn't get me the count of objects

Answer (score 1):

You can get the total number of buttons by using descriptive approach.

```
Set odesc = description.Create()
odesc("micclass").value="WebButton"
Set i = Browser("creationtime:=0").Page("title:=Google").ChildObjects(odesc)

Msgbox i.Count()

Set i = Nothing : Set odesc = Nothing
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying, Yes I know how to do it by first creating Description object. However, shouldn't there be a way of doing this using static programming approach.

Comment: Can I do this using Childobjects method, Eg I did following,

' Set P = Browser("creationtime:=0").Page("title:=Google").ChildObjects(WebButton("name:=Google Search"))

MsgBox P.Count'


And it gives me count as 62, how is this possible ,there's only 1 webbutton with name 'Google Search' so result should have been 1

Comment: You can not use ChildObjects using the syntax that you've mentioned above, because you are not passing an object as a parameter for ChildObjects. Check the UFT help file documentation. You've to create Description object and pass it as parameter.

Comment: Hi, Thanks so much for replying.So, this WebButton("name:=Google Search") is nt considered an object which we are passing as parameter? Yes, anyways above syntax not working.Thus, the only way to find no. of objects on a webpage or any windowbased application is by using Dynamic descriptive programming?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You are actually trying to get a count of the **child** webbutton objects on that **page** object. With the original code that you posted, if there is more than one webbutton object on the page with the descriptors you're using, QTP will throw a multiple object matches found error.

Nelly's code regarding the description property is what you're after. If you are specifically looking for the count of all webbutton objects with a type:=submit, you can add additional description properties:

```
odesc("micclass").value="WebButton"
odesc("type").value="submit"
```

doing this will filter out buttons that don't have the matching type value